# Генератор документации для Delphi / Pascal

Tags: delphi, документация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь генератор документации (типа `Doxygen` или `Javadoc`) для `Delphi`.
Желательно свободный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так используйте doxygen. Если внимательно почитать [документацию](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html), то там сказано, что нужно использовать [Pas2dox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pas2dox/).

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.